# Why does my Unity ECS simulation move all objects to the same position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I am trying to learn the Unity Dots / ECS system, and am running into a really incomprehensible issue that has me completely stuck. I am trying to build a *life* simulation that has a collection of cells spawn and move around. But I haven't even got that far yet.

The full code for my project can be found [here](https://github.com/joegatling/test_simulation01), but the snippet that isn't working is the following:

```
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Mathematics;

[BurstCompile]
[UpdateInGroup(typeof(SimulationSystemGroup))]
public partial struct UpdateSystem : ISystem
{
    [BurstCompile]
    void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)
    {
        float3 position; 

        foreach(var cell in SystemAPI.Query<CellAspect>())
        {
            // The following operation causes all the objects to be moved to the exact same position!
            position = cell.position;
            cell.position = position;
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to be as simple as can be. I iterate through all my "cells" and I store the position, and then assign it directly back. When I run this, all cells end up in the same position. I tried outputting the position (`Debug.Log(cell.position)`) and the output is as expected, with each position being where they were randomly spawned.

I get the impression that there is a fundamental concept that I am not getting here, but with how the the ECS api keeps changing, it is really had to find reliable tutorials online.

The definition of CellAspect is as follows:

```
public readonly partial struct CellAspect : IAspect
{
    private readonly TransformAspect _transformAspect;

    private readonly RefRW<CellProperties> _cellProperties;    

    public TransformAspect transform => _transformAspect;
    
    public float3 velocity
    {
        get => _cellProperties.ValueRO.velocity;
        set => _cellProperties.ValueRW.velocity = value;
    }

    public float3 position 
    {
        get => _transformAspect.WorldPosition;
        set => _transformAspect.WorldPosition = value;
    }

    public float detectionRadius => _cellProperties.ValueRO.detectionRadius;

}
```

Comment: You could create a Movement Component with a float3 property and give it random direction when baking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

#### NOTE: `TransformAspect` is gone as of `entities 1.0.0-pre.65` (2023-03-21)

---

`IAspect` was introduced in 1.0 and I don't like it already. This is an example of why. Because, as you will learn here, it obfuscates things that should be very explicit and apparent.

This is (part of) your `CellAspect`:

```
public readonly partial struct CellAspect : IAspect
{
    private readonly TransformAspect _transformAspect;

    public float3 position 
    {
        get => _transformAspect.WorldPosition;
        set => _transformAspect.WorldPosition = value;
    }
}
```

Notice that you created a property named `position` and it changes what exactly? `WorldPosition` of course. How is that even important? Well, it CAN be important if, for example, you initialized an entity's local position (`LocalTransform`) and never gave it a frame of time to propagate to become world position before overwriting this local position with this hidden `_transformAspect.WorldPosition` back to it's original prefab's value.

I suggest you either delete this vague `position` property OR introduce `worldPosition` and `localPosition` in it's place:

```
public readonly partial struct CellAspect : IAspect
{
    private readonly TransformAspect _transformAspect;
    public float3 worldPosition
    {
        get => _transformAspect.WorldPosition;
        set => _transformAspect.WorldPosition = value;// surprise: writes to local pos too!
    }
    public float3 localPosition 
    {
        get => _transformAspect.LocalPosition;
        set => _transformAspect.LocalPosition = value;// haven't checked but probably writes to world pos too
    }
}
```

#### TL;DR:

```
void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)
{
    foreach(var cell in SystemAPI.Query<CellAspect>())
    {
        float3 pos = cell.localPosition;
        cell.localPosition = pos;
    }
}
```